# Error using class attributes for method inside class

Tags: python, object, typeerror

I have a class with a couple of attributes and a method in that class that I want to use those attributes in, as well as passing in an additional argument. I'm getting a TypeError and I don't fully understand why.

```
class Strategy:

    def __init__(self, val, tof):
        self.val = val
        self.tof = tof

    def stand(self, item):
        if item < self.val:
            return False
        else:
            if self.tof == True:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

When I run my unittest, passing in:

> self.assertTrue(pythonfile.Strategy.stand(10, True, 20))

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: stand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Should the line be `self.assertTrue(pythonfile.Strategy(10, True).stand(20))`?

Comment: `stand()` is a method that must be called on an instance, not the class. So you have to create an instance first.